# window.open() returns null in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

It works in a simple call, but returns null inside $http. How can I create a window if I need the result of $http?

```
window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=300,height=200,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0');  // OK

$http({
       ...
}).then(function(response) {
   console.log(response.data.MyData); // correct
   var WinPrint = window.open('','','left=0,top=0,width=300,height=200,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0');   // null
});
```

Comment: Is it possible that your $http request is failing?  I wrote an example and `window` is visible in both outside and inside the $http success callback.

Comment: No, $http works correctly. I've updated the source code in the example

Comment: I believe the window has to be opened exactly after a user interaction (e.g. click), otherwise it is blocked by the browser. Try opening the window before the `$http` call and keep the reference to it. You can change the window location later.

Comment: Vladimir Zdenek, it's a great idea, thanks a lot